# Can people play with fields using PowerPivot?

Tags: excel-services, powerpivot

I began on a BI job a few months ago and one of my first tasks is to replace our current way to access the SSAS cubes. It is a custom web application based on OWC (which is now  deprecated) and it's starting to get cumbersome to install owc11 on every new client.

I was trying Excel Services and PowerPivot on SharePoint 2010 but I can't seem to find a way for the user to play (drag-n-drop filters, columns, rows) with the fields and totals. The way our current system does:

[image: current]

Is this even possible with SharePoint, ExcelServices and PowerPivot or should I be looking for another solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use [PowerView](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213579.aspx).

Here's some info on how you can deploy and configure it on SharePoint 2010:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/karang/archive/2012/04/13/step-by-step-guide-of-installing-power-view-with-powerpivot-2012.aspx

http://blog.cloudshare.com/2012/05/22/step-by-step-guide-to-installing-sharepoint-with-sql-2012-powerpivot-powerview-and-reporting-services/